# Microsoft Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

The problem is with Outlook event, which is not triggered in the specific case I describe below:

1. I click on some random file on the desktop with right button, I choose "send to" -> "mail recipient" (Microsoft Outlook).
2. Outlook opens new mail with this file attached.
3. I send e-mail and the problem occurs -> event "ItemSend" is not triggered (like sending e-mail did not occur).

I have procedures to be executed afterwards.

If I send e-mail normally, event is triggered properly. The problem is with this "send to" shortcut.

Outlook 2016, Windows 10.

Any VBA coding available?

Due to company policy, I can't write any C# plugin.

Thanks for help.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question and so it would be off topic on StackOverflow. The good news is that we have a site called SuperUser that is for questions like this.

Comment: @HackSlash - this *is* a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

The events don't fire for the messages generated by Simple MAPI or mailto links. This is on purpose.

The only workaround is to use `Items.ItemAdd` even on the Sent Items folder, but it fires immediate after the message is sent, not before.